# Getting Fullname in Access 2007 through CreateObject("Application")..?

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-word, vba

I'm trying to get the full name of the current db file in Access 2007 through the `CreateObject()` method, but it doesn't work  and simply returns an empty string. I'm using `CreateObject()` because the code will be used in multiple Microsoft Office products. I believe the correct terminology for this is "late binding"..?

For example, this works...

```
Public Sub ThisWorks()
    Dim obj1 As Object
    Dim obj2 As Object
    Set obj1 = Access.Application
    Set obj2 = obj1.CurrentProject
    Debug.Print obj2.FullName
End Sub
```

...but this does not work...

```
Public Sub ThisDoesNotWork()
    Dim obj1 As Object
    Dim obj2 As Object
    Set obj1 = CreateObject("Access.Application") 'This is the only change.
    Set obj2 = obj1.CurrentProject
    Debug.Print obj2.FullName
End Sub
```

Why doesn't this work..?

Are there any changes that would make it work..?

Here's a complete example of how it's being used...

```
Public Function CurrentFilename() As String
    
    'This function tries to return the full name & path of the currently open file. It's
    'based on the idea that all (or most?) implementations of VBA have the foundation
    'object called "Application", and a child object with a property that has the
    'filename. The design of this function should allow it to run in any software
    'product that supports VBA. It might even run in VBScript too, but that's not been
    'tested. If any error occurs, or the product cannot return the filename, or the
    'function does not recognize the product, an empty string is returned. As time goes
    'on, more software product names can be added to the Select Case, but for now it's
    'just Microsoft Office products.

    Dim productName As String
    Dim obj1 As Object
    Dim obj2 As Object
    Dim filename As String
    Dim msgStyle As VbMsgBoxStyle
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    msgStyle = vbApplicationModal + vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
    
    productName = Application.Name
       
    Select Case productName
        Case "Microsoft Access"
            Set obj1 = CreateObject("Access.Application")
            Set obj2 = obj1.CurrentProject
            filename = obj2.FullName
        Case "Microsoft Excel"
            Set obj1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Set obj2 = obj1.ActiveWorkbook
            filename = obj2.FullName
        Case "Outlook"
            'Returns the path\name of the current default *.OST file.
            Set obj1 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set obj2 = obj1.Session.DefaultStore
            filename = obj2.FilePath
        Case "Microsoft PowerPoint"
            Set obj1 = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
            Set obj2 = obj1.ActivePresentation
            filename = obj2.FullName
        Case "Microsoft Publisher"
            Set obj1 = CreateObject("Publisher.Application")
            Set obj2 = obj1.ActiveDocument
            filename = obj2.FullName
        Case "Microsoft Word"
            Set obj1 = CreateObject("Application.ActivePresentation")
            Set obj2 = obj1.Session.DefaultStore
            filename = obj2.FullName
        Case Else
            'Optional error message to the user.
            MsgBox "The current VBA runtime environment is not recognized.", _
                    msgStyle, "Error getting file name."
    End Select
    
    CurrentFilename = filename
    
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

    Dim msg As String
    Dim dot As String
    
    'Be a grammar grouch. Ensure the description ends with a period/fullstop.
    If VBA.Right(err.Description, 1) <> "." Then
        dot = "."
    End If
    
    msg = ""
    msg = msg & "Error:" & vbTab & VBA.CStr(err.Number)
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    msg = msg & "Desc:" & vbTab & err.Description & dot
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    msg = msg & "Source:" & vbTab & err.Source
    
    MsgBox msg, msgStyle, "Runtime Error"
    
    'Do not return from the error. Just exit and return an empty string.
    'Resume Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem why the late bound version is not working is because you ask the the VBA engine to hand you a new `Application` not the currently running one. In early bound code `CreateObject("Access.Application")` is equivalent to `new Access.Application`. (The string "Access.Application` describes the type you want to get here.) That is not what you want.

On the other hand, when you assign `Access.Application`, you are assigning the global variable `Access.Application` to the object, which is the currently running instance of Access.

Note that this is a general problem of your approach.

Since you always want to access the current `Application` object, you could simply assign this unqualified to `obj1` and procede from there. This always resolves to the reference with the highest priortity in the reference dialog, which will be the one of the host application.

Comment: But if I use `Set hostApp = Application`, the compiler chokes on the members from the other products. For instance, if I run this in Access, the assignment for CurrentProject works fine, but it trips up on the Excel ActiveWorkbook class with the error "Method or data member not found." That was the reason I was trying to use CreateObject(<LibraryName>). The compiler won't evaluate the library name and what would be unrecognized methods & properties if early-bound are then allowed to slide past without an error.

Comment: Did you as assign `Application` to a variable declared as `Object`? That is important. When I run your code in Excel with `Set obj1 = Application` pulled in front of the `Select` statement, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Just for background: you make code late bound by using variables of type `Object`. The type `Object` itself defines next to no members. However, it is a so-called _extendable_ interface. For such interfaces, the compiler never checks whether a member you call actually exists; the check only happens at run-time. Another examples of such an interface is `ADODB.Connection`, which allows you to access stored procedures as members.

Comment: Ahh yes, I understand. I have yet to work with interfaces out here in the wild, but we covered them quite a lot in the four semesters of Java I took to finally finish my degree last year. Thinking forward: is there a way to know when any class is extendable or not, like in the Object Browser or some such..?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to get the information whether an interface is extendable either from the documentation or by inspecting the type library. Anyway, most interfaces are not extendable and you are not able to define extendable interfaces in VBA yourself.